# jquery show alert on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a simple log in at the top of my page, when the user enters their id thats on my json file their name appears in a welcome alert(the welcome alert is avaiable on ready and the name appears inside when the user logs in).  I want the alert to be hidden but when the users enters their code (there is no username just a code) this alert appears with the name.

Here is the log in text and button:

```
<div class="alert alert-info"><input type="text" id="userName" value> <button type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Login</button></div>
```

Here is the alert:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="loginalert"<strong>Welcome</strong></div>
```

and here is the js getting the corresponding name to appear:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
//console.log("clicked login");
   $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
      var id = $('#userName').val();
      //console.log(id);
      for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
        if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
          $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');
        }
      }
   });
}); });
```

the json file includes the users id (which is the code for now)  : 001

and their name

when the code is entered to the login text box their name appears on the page to indicate what user has logged in

I also wanted to know.. if there was no corresponding id to the four i have included in my json is there any way to get this alert to appear instead of the login alert, this would be like a you have entered an invalid code -

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>
```

(also to be hidden on page load/ready)

Can anyone help out guys please?

Kind regards

Comment: what is the problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: I have modified your script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Hide alert when page loads
$("#loginalert").hide();    
    $("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
    //console.log("clicked login");
       $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
          var id = $('#userName').val();
          //console.log(id);
          for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
            if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
              $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');      
              //show the alert after loading the information
                $("#loginalert").stop().fadeIn('slow').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 3000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('#contact').fadeIn('slow');
            });
            }
          }
       });
    }); 
});
```

For Error Message try:

Modify your div to this,

```
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="ErrorMessageAlert"> <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>
```

Thereafter modify your scripts again to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Hide alert when page loads
$("#loginalert").hide();    
$("#ErrorMessageAlert").hide();
    $("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
    //console.log("clicked login");
       $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
          var id = $('#userName').val();
          //console.log(id);
          for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
            if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
              $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');      
              //show the alert after loading the information
                $("#loginalert").show();
            }else
            {
                $("#ErrorMessageAlert").show();
            }

            );
            }
          }
       });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: brilliant! worked perfectly! I wanted to ask you though.. how I would modify your script to make the welcome message stay on the page instead of fade out? also is there any way to get  this div : <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>   to appear if the user does not enter a valid id   (there are 4 ids from the json file 001,002,003 and 004)  so if they were to enter nothing or an invalid id and click the button that alert would appear

Comment: I have update my answer please check it out for your second question.

Comment: Hi Neo!  thank you very much for your second answer - this did not work as both alerts appear when the page is loaded and the json did not load on to the welcome one, would it be a problem with my script? do you need any more of my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your both alert forms hidden by default by adding `hidden` class and then through query `show()`-http://api.jquery.com/show/ display needed one

```
<style>
    .hidden{
        display:none;
    } 
</style>

<div class="alert alert-info hidden"><input type="text" id="userName" value> <button type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Login</button></div>
<div class="alert alert-danger hidden"> <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>

<script>
$.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {

   var id = $('#userName').val();
   // Defined to keep if match found in loop
   var matchFound = false;

   for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
     if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {

       $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');
       // Show Welcome alert
       $(".alert-info").show();
       matchFound = true;
       break;
     }
   }

  // which means no match found and matchFound is not equal to true
   if( !matchFound ){
      // Show Error alert
      $(".alert-danger").show();
   }
});
</script>
```